# laravel nova download file from path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

with an action I need to be able to download a file. How can I do?

with this code

```
return Action::download('https://example.com/invoice.pdf', 'Invoice.pdf');
```

a url must be passed, I would like to pass the path (ex. storage/folder/filename.xx)

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Make a route that downloads the invoice.

Then `Action::redirect('invoice')` to that route

```php
Route::get('invoice', function() {

    $path = auth()->user()->latestInvoice();

    return response()->download($path);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Storage::url()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-urls) function. For example :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;    
...    

class YourAction extends Action
{

    public function handle()
    {
        return Action::download(Storage::url('folder/filename.xxx'), 'Name.xxx');
    }
}
```

**Note :**

> When using the local driver, all files that should be publicly
> accessible should be placed in the storage/app/public directory.
> Furthermore, you should [create a symbolic link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) at public/storage which
> points to the storage/app/public directory.